# Integrate ALM with eclipse workspace

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver, alm

We are having requirement to integrate ALM with eclipse. If we execute the automated test case from ALM then Java class which is in eclipse should run and selenium code present in Java class should execute. Based on the result test case present in ALM should get updated.

I have tried all the internet pages but didn't get solution.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code where you get stuck.

Comment: This way is very hard to implement and I haven't seen products which supports such workflow flawlessly, so I would advice you to run your java/selenium tests on some modern CI/CD and then export your test results into ALM. We are developing tool, called [Bumblebee](https://agiletestware.com/bumblebee) which allows you to integrate your selenium tests with ALM.